# iOS Internet Reachability Getting Called Twice

Tags: ios, objective-c

View controller to determine the reachability and if the app is connected to the internet I have this code here:

```
//Check for internet
    internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");

        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Someone broke the internet :(");
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Important" message: @"You are not connected to the internet.  Please try again." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show];
        });
    };

    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];

    }
```

This all works perfectly however when I don't have internet the alert view pops up and then when I do get internet again the entire script runs again and there is a small delay to when it detects the internet is being connected to when it actually returns google.com and for that reason it checks and claims the internet is not reachable before saying it is finally connected.  Point being that since it claims that the internet is not connected twice it brings up the UIAlertView twice.  Is there anything I can do to only get the alertview to show up once.  I have tried moving this script around and I am not too familiar with more I can do on the alert view to get it to not be called again.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are u using wifi or 3g connection?

Answer (score 2):

They correct way to implement this is

```
-(BOOL)reachable {
       Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}




if([self reachable])
{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");

        });
}else{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Important" message: @"You are not connected to the internet.  Please try again." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Use the above code while targeting for iOS 9. Because rateability code will trouble you for checking internet connection. This code save me.

Answer (score 2):

Since Reachability tied to SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback so the answer by [matt](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2238#issuecomment-51943881) is also relevant to Apple's Reachability:

> This is expected behavior.
>
> AFNetworkReachabilityManager ties into
>   SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback, which triggers any time that
>   SCNetworkReachabilityFlags change. Although the flags change in each
>   callback, the overall on / off distinction may not change between
>   callbacks. This isn't great, but there's not much to be done about it
>   without changing the contract with SystemConfiguration.
>
> I will say this: your current use of reachability is strongly
>   discouraged. Users should never have a modal alert triggered on
>   reachability. If anything, reachability should be communicated in a
>   non-modal view that does not prevent the user from interacting with
>   the app.

*Credit goes to **matt***

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this also

```
- (BOOL)connected
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);

}
```

to use it

```
if( [self connected])
{
   //   Do your stuff

}
else
{
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Important" message: @"You are not connected to the internet.  Please try again." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Does that work even when the power of the router modem is off?

Comment: How I used your code now it doesn't constantly check for the connection.  Did i put everything in the right place?

Comment: the code in ReachabilityExample.zip does not detect when internet state changed. it's only check when view loaded.

Comment: @de_la_vega_66: for that you have to add observer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem in swift 3.0 the solution I came up with was,

> 

1. by making global Reachibility object
2. callling observer from viewdidLoad() instead of viewWillAppear()
3. removing observer in viewwillDisappear()

> 

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool){
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        print("--- : viewWillDisappear :----")

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: ReachabilityChangedNotification, object: reachabilitee)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name("dismissLVC"), object: nil)
}
```