# Reachability reachable and unreachableBlock are called multiple times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

Im using Reachability to check the network status for my app, everithing works OK except that in iOS 9.0.1 or higher the `reachableBlock` and `unreachableBlock` are called twice, which takes me into a big trouble.

This is only happening in iOS 9.0.1 and iOS 9.1 Beta.

And heres an example of my code:

```
-(void)checkServerConnection{
//This nslog is to check the method is called only once.
    NSLog(@"Check Server Connection");

    Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
    [reach startNotifier];
    reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
//This NSLOG is called twice
        NSLog(@"Reachability reachable block");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//This NSLOG is called twice
            NSLog(@"REACHABLE!");     
        });
    };

    reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
//Same story for this one..
        NSLog(@"UNREACHABLE!");
}
}
```

Please if someone have solved this issue let me know how.

Comment: The reason it is happening: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35453136/4260691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just what i have in mind, this should be a comment but it's too long.

Please let me explain what is happening in your code...
I'm not really sure about this one but i think iOS 9.0.1 and iOS 9.1 is keeping the variable because of this `[reach startNotifier];`..

When you call the method `-(void)checkServerConnection` you are creating a `new Reachability* reach` and so on..

IF you will call the method again, it will create a `new` `Reachability* reach` and there is an existing one..

Possible solution is to create a global variable (Reachability* reach) that will be reused everytime the method is called.

---

Probably something like this:

```
Reachability* reachVar;
// i've changed your variable name hope that's okay, just for example.

-(void)checkServerConnection{

    NSLog(@"Check Server Connection");

    if (reachVar == nil)
    {
        reachVar = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];
        [reachVar startNotifier];
    }
    reachVar.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        NSLog(@"Reachability reachable block");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"REACHABLE!");     
        });
    };

    reachVar.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        NSLog(@"UNREACHABLE!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this didnt work, I created the global variable but the error persist, the method is only called ONCE at viewDidLoad

Comment: It's the same on iOS 10.2, I think adding a global var is necessary.

Comment: Not a solution. Still handler calls twice.